# How to replace callee function using C macro?

Tags: c, macros

I'm having a problem with using C macros and was wondering if anybody could help.

I trying to replace callee function using C macro or remove parenthesis of function call. The callee function is passed to macro in form of function call.

I want to transform code to like this:

```
SOME_MACRO(any_function1(param0, param1))  ->  myfunc(param0, param1)
SOME_MACRO(any_function2(param0, param1, param2))  ->  myfunc(param0, param1, param2)
```

Is it possible?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No, you cannot replace the content of your parameters. You could try to pass function name and parameters in separate arguments

Comment: If you want to replace all function calls in whole file, you could define a macro for that name only: `#define any_function other_function` but you need to do this for each used function.

Comment: The C preprocessor is a simple mind, its `#define` directive is little more than a search and replace mechanism. Gerhardh's idea is often practical. -- If you use GCC, the option `-E` is helpful to see what the preprocessed source looks like. Other compilers might have similar options.

Comment: Thanks, I will transform the code using string match & replace before compilation.

Comment: Do you have to replace a very specific `any_function` in `SOME_MACRO`. Or all function calls that happen to be in `SOME_MACRO`?

Comment: @tstanisl I have to replace all function calls (not just a function named any_function) in SOME_MACRO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write a macro like `SOME_MACRO(any_function(param0, param1))` because the contents would be regarded as one single preprocessor token and you wouldn't be able to grab the `any_function` part of it.

Instead simply do `#define any_function other_function`.

---

More advanced topic: in case you need to change parameters or add type safety etc, create a "wrapper macro". Take for example this artificial macro:

```
#define any_function(x, y) _Generic((x), int: other_function) (x,y,z)
```

This example does 3 things:

- Replace calls to  `any_function` with `other_function`
- Enforce a stricter type safety on the first argument than what's required by a simple function call. For example if you require that the `x` argument *must* be `int` and not `unsigned int`, `long`, `short` or similar, which would otherwise be fine to pass to a function taking `int` as parameter ("lvalue conversion" would occur).
- Add a 3rd parameter `z` to the call, not present in the caller code, for compatibility reasons. Similarly, we could as well drop one of the parameters or change the order of them.